# How to "uninstall" Plymouth Themes

Tags: 12.04, plymouth

I have been working with custom Plymouth themes and have ran into a little confusion. For a reason unclear to me, you have to enter the following:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /lib/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /lib/plymouth/themes/THEMENAME/THEMENAME.plymouth 100
```

into the Terminal to get the

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

Command to recognize your theme and then run the initramfs update.

My question is.. what is the SAFE way to uninstall (delete) a theme so that no fatal errors error? I would just delete the folder but I don't know if that would mess anything up within the system.

Any input is appropriated c:

Answer (score 5):

It can be done:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --remove default.plymouth /path/folder/theme/to/uninstall/file-theme.plymouth
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is just as simple as deleting the theme's folder.. the theme can't be currently selected as the boot theme however.. that could cause issues.